# É possível alterar o tipo de uma PK, que já tem relacionamento ou somente recriando a tb?

Tags: mysql

Criei uma PK no Mysql em uma tabela com sucesso, mas defini o tipo de modo errado fiz como char e preciso alterar para int, isso é possível?

Essa tabela já está como fk em outras tb.

Não é possível, que não exista nenhuma forma de alterar apenas o tipo, será que não tem mesmo?

Até onde levantei parece que apenas recriando mesmo, mas antes de fazer isso, quero consultar os especialistas.

A versão é 8.0.26 Community Server-GPL.

Estou fazendo via Command Line.

Obrigado por qualquer Luz! Que não seja recriar a tabela! (kk).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Alterando o tipo da PK para int:

```
**ALTER TABLE nome_da_tabela MODIFY COLUMN nome_da_coluna INT;**
```

Adicionando uma PK para a Tabela:

```
**ALTER TABLE nome_da_tabela ADD PRIMARY KEY (nome_da_coluna_id);**
```

(Bônus)
Adicionando uma tabela comum:

```
**ALTER TABLE nome_da_tabela ADD COLUMN nome_da_coluna VARCHAR(30)**;
```

Answer (score -1):

Procuro a mesma solução. E até agora, constatei que é possivel excluindo as FK para esse campo PK. Em seguida você pode desmarcar seu campo pk, assim ele não será mais PK, crie um campo chamado "id" por exemplo e defina como int , autoincrement e defina esse id como PK. Assim sua tabela terá uma nova PK. Em seguida com consegue mudar o tipo do campo original.

Vá nas tabelas que tinha as FK para esse campo e mude o tipo.

Depois volte tudo: defina o campo original para PK e remova o campo id.

Assim, os campos FK e PK devem ser do mesmo tipo, assim você consegue criar novamente as FK.

Da um trabalho do cão. mas até agora vi que assim vai. estou postergando para fazer isso. fiz apenas um teste e deu certo. Mas quero procurar uma outra solução. tenho dezenas de tabelas para mudar.

Comment: Perfeito Bruno! Isso é coisa para Gigante! Fui nessa linha mesmo, e consegui! Abraço!